# Draw text follow the path: how to snap text on one side of path?

Tags: svg

[Illustration](https://codepen.io/BanterFace/pen/QQMKLr).

```
<text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#pseudo_c" startOffset="0%" style="font-family: Roboto Black; font-size: 2vw;">Sample text</textPath>
</text>
```

The problem is the text appears on both sides of the path if font-size is big enough and on inner side – if size is small, but I want to text will be on the single outer side.

How can I do this?

Generally, there are [side](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TextPathElementSideAttribute) property, but it doesn't work in my example (probably because it was made for closed shapes).

Comment: The path loops back on itself, if you don't want the text to be on both sides, don't have the path loop back.

Comment: @RobertLongson, but if I delete 'Z' in path's d-attribute (to unloop it), text still be on a both sides.